How do I programmatically authenticate and connect using psql to my Aurora DSQL cluster?
I was able to use the DSQL console to get an authentication token, but now I'm trying to connect programmatically without having to use the console.
i'm using the following psql command and providing the token when prompted for the password:
PGSSLMODE=require \
psql --dbname postgres \
--username admin \
--host redacted

note: since StackOverflow encourages answering your own questions, i figured i'd go ahead and post the question and answer for anyone who might have a similar question.

AWS CLI provides a token gen method (ref: CLI docs). example usage:
aws dsql generate-db-connect-admin-auth-token \
--region us-east-1 \
--expires-in 3600 \
--hostname redacted

to make this easier in the future, i wrote a little "psql-ish" shell script:
#!/bin/bash
# connect to Aurora DSQL in a psql-ish way
# TL;DR - generate auth token with AWS CLI and use psql to connect to the cluster

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then echo "Missing Endpoint. Usage: $0 Endpoint" >&2 && exit 1; fi

ENDPOINT_REGION=$(echo $1 | cut -d "." -f 3)

export PGPASSWORD=$(aws dsql generate-db-connect-admin-auth-token \
--region $ENDPOINT_REGION \
--expires-in 3600 \
--hostname $1)

export PGSSLMODE=require

psql --host $1 \
--username admin \
--dbname postgres \
--quiet


note: modification required to use non-admin role

usage: ./admin-psqli.sh foo0bar1baz2quux3quuux4.dsql.us-east-1.on.aws
